# When I set the height of a DIV, it breaks CSS' "column-count" layout in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cross-browser

I have a layout with 3 columns (with CSS `column-count: 3;`).

In these columns there are images using `background-image`, which I set from getting the `src` of the image inside the parent div (which is `visibility:hidden`) with jQuery.

Additionally, I get the height of the previously mentioned image and set it as the height of the parent div:

```
var imgHeight = $(this).find('img').height();
$(this).css('height', imgHeight + 'px');
```

I figured out, that setting a height on the parent div (called `.item`) destroys the 3 column layout (only in Chrome (62.0.3202.94)). It doesn't matter if I set the height through jQuery or directly in CSS.

Surprisingly, it's working in Internet Explorer. I didn't test it on Firefox because I can't install it in my company's network.

Unfortunately, I can't provide a fiddle, because I can't reproduce the problem there, so I hope you're okay with that. [Here's a the codepen I made.](https://codepen.io/tobiasglaus/pen/LOLvZz) Open it in IE and Chrome to see the difference.

Does anyone know what causes this problem? Thanks alot for your help!

Comment: Why are you adding fixed `width` on each element and still using `column-count`?

Comment: Your HTML structure for the expanded content is probably not the best way to do that effect.

Comment: @Marian07 jQuery gets the position and size of the item and sets those as CSS values, aswell as `position:absolute`. That's to be able to transition it to `top:0;left:0` on click.

Comment: @Marian07 How would you stucture it then? Thanks for your help!

Comment: One html element for all full-width images. Data will be set on it based on the clicked element. This way you're not limited to nest full-width content inside each element

Comment: @Marian07 Yes, that'd be possible, but like that the transition from "column item" to full width isn't possible anymore, right?

Comment: Another approach for that effect might be required.